# Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: any[]) => void'

Tags: typescript

```
function on(event: string, listener: Function) {
    console.log('on event: ', event, 'typeof listener:', typeof (listener));
    listener();
}

function on1(event: string, listener: (...args: any[]) => void) {
    console.log('on event: ', event, 'typeof listener:', typeof (listener));
    listener();
}

function createCallback(a: number): Function {
    let f = (a: number) => {
        console.log('return a:', a);
        return (a: number) => { return a + 1 };
    };
    return f(a);
}

let f = createCallback(1);
console.log('type of f', typeof (f));
// on("start", f);
on1("start", f);
```

In the above code, `on("start", f)` works fine but `on1("start", f);` returns error

```
main.ts:22:14 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Function' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: any[]) => void'.
  Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(...args: any[]): void'.

22 on1("start", f);
                ~
```

If I remove the `Function` type assertion of `createCallback`, `on1("start", f)` works, isn't `Function` a general type to represent closures?

The original question comes from this commit, https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/commit/96545154cc6488643a7064a6dc4ec9726c7af12a#diff-7d84e08967cded0b99ed4328aab0a1a8L291

I don't understand why he changes `Function` to `(...args: any[]) => void` which makes my code break.

Comment: “isn't Function a general type to represent closures?” — right, it’s a *general* type, but your function `on1` requires a more specific type. Just like `Any` is a general type, and can’t be bound to a more specific type (but can itself bind anything).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20007) to allow something like this, for `Function` to be assignable to `(...args: any[]) => any`. The reason that this is not the current behavior is:

> The original intention of Function is to not be callable. in other words, Function to function types should be like unknown to other types, but not callable. we have since relaxed this restriction giving Function a callable behavior in the compiler through special casing. We have talked about making this a --noImplicitAny error since, it is really unsafe to call Functions.

I suggest you up-vote the suggestion if this is important to you.

I would generally stay way from `Function` it's not a type-safe away to express function signatures. For your case I would use the following:

```
function on(event: string, listener: (...args: any[]) => void) {
    console.log('on event: ', event, 'typeof listener:', typeof (listener));
    listener();
}

function createCallback(a: number)  { // we can omit the return type or be explicit and type it as (a: number) => number
    let f = (a: number) => {
        console.log('return a:', a);
        return (a: number) => { return a + 1 };
    };
    return f(a);
}

let f = createCallback(1); // (a: number) => number 
on("start", f);
```

Comment: @xcaptain added a sample with what I would do for you use case, you can write the function type explicitly in the return type of `createCallback` or you can let the compiler infer it.

Comment: Thanks I got it, I created a more complicated example here https://gist.github.com/xcaptain/2ccfc878dbc0bed4813924614a057494#file-typescript_function_type_error_test-ts-L27, do you think it's a good idea not to specific return type if return a closure since `(...args: any[]) => void` is like saying nothing.

Comment: @xcaptain with or without the explicit return type at call-site you will get the same errors and code completion. The only thing the explicit return type will add is a validation that you return the corect value from inside the `create*` functions. It's you decision whether this is worth the length type you have to type in for complex return types.